# How to specialise template class constructor in C++

Tags: c++, c++-templates

I'm practicing C++, and I want to implement a few data structures using templates.

I want to create a constructor for `List<char>` that accepts a C++ `string` as a parameter, but I don't want to create such a constructor for the rest of the types (as it wouldn't make much sense to create a `List<double>` from a `string`, for example).

Is there a way to achieve this in C++?

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> class CollectionInterface {
public:
    virtual T get();
    virtual void set(int index, T value);
    virtual void add(T value);
    virtual int length();
};

template <typename T> class ListItem {
public:
    T value;
    ListItem* next;
    ListItem* prev;
};

template <typename T> class List: public CollectionInterface<T> {
public:
    List(){}
    List(T* arr, int length){
        init(arr,length);
    }
    ~List(){

    }

protected:
    void init(T* arr, int length){

    }
    ListItem<T>* first;
    ListItem<T>* last;
};

template<char> class List<char> {
public:
    List<char>(string s){
        char char_array[s.length() + 1];
        strcpy(char_array, s.c_str());
        this->init(char_array,s.length());
    }
};

int main()
{
    List<char> list("Hello World!");

    //cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It shows the following errors:

> Line 40: Partial specialization of 'List' does not use any of its template parameters
>
> Line 45: No member named 'init' in 'List<char>'

Comment: It's `template<> class List<char> { ... };` to fully specialize the template class.

Comment: Also VLAs are not part of the standard and therefore shouldn't be used. There's no need for this anyways: `this->init(s.data(), s.length());` should do the trick and you may want to create a copy here anyways, so `this->init(s.c_str(), s.length());` may be sufficient, if you change the signature of `init` to `void init(T const* arr, int length)`

Comment: is there any way to call the non-specialised functions from List<char>? I get the error: No member named 'init' in 'List<char>'

Comment: Unfortunately the question was closed while I was working on an answer, but basically I'd implement the conversion outside of the class and introduce a constructor template limited via a concept (or SFINAE pre C++20). Here's an example I've created with a simplified class: https://godbolt.org/z/Yn7GYMTsc

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you don't need to specialize the entire `List` class.  Just provide your `List<T>` class with an overloaded constructor for `string` input, and then use SFINAE to disable that constructor for non-`char` lists, eg:

```
template <typename T> class List: public CollectionInterface<T> {
public:
    ...

    template <typename U = T>
    List (typename enable_if<is_same<U, char>::value, string>::type const &s)
    {
        init(const_cast<char*>(s.c_str()), s.length());
    }

    ...
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/aYuUjD)